# My mouse doesn't show up during gameplay

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings, windows-8

I am playing Age of Empires on Windows 8, through my Mac with Parallels, and I am thinking that it is either a problem with Windows 8 or Parallels because it didn't happen on my home computer running Windows 7. Any advice? I'm using a MacBook with Retina display 15in and Parallels 8, running Windows 8.

Comment: Do you have a controller plugged in? Some games "helpfully" hide my mouse cursor when I leave my controller plugged in, even if I'm not using the controller

Comment: AoE 2 doesn't support controllers so I doubt that is the case here.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure that controllers would do that, but no I don't have one :/

Comment: Pfft, "using a mouse for a strategy game". Try playing Dwarf Fortress.

Comment: Turns out Windows 8 doesn't really like Age of Empires, I just installed Windows 7 and it works great!

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer [here](https://forum.parallels.com/threads/invisible-mouse-pointer-in-old-windows-game.103599/), posted by carlar

1. On your windows desktop, right click on the shortcut for age of empires 2.
2. Go to Properties.
3. Select the Shortcut tab
4. Beside "Target" there's a field that says "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Games\Age of Empires II\EMPIRES2.EXE" or wherever it is that you've installed. After the quotation mark, leave a space and type "normalmouse" (no quotations).
5. Hit apply
6. Hit OK

Voila! You've just altered the command line to get rid of the invisible stylized mouse.

Answer (score 3):

Some games I play on the PC offer "Custom Cursor" settings, which for some reason always hides my mouse. I have to go into options and turn it off. It's a pain, because the cursor is invisible, and you have to watch for buttons to change slightly most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Try right-clicking the game start up icon and selecting properties. In the 'Target' box you get the string that launches the game. Immediately after that type the word normalmouse and press apply. Try it then.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the comments, I found the same problem and the only workaround was to use normalmouse. Nevertheless, GameRanger won't run it with this attribute. Looking at the registry that setting is:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Games\Age of Empires\1.00

The name of the key is Custom Mouse, changing the value to 2 worked for me.

Comment: 'A normal mouse', or is 'normalmouse' software?

Answer (score 0):

you sure the mouse isn't just flickering real fast, either way, could be your graphics card/drivers?, my computer is Windows 7 and when i load the game up the main menu is really screwy and when i play a map, some things in the map have weird pink pixels around them, it's the reason why i've stopped playing it and got Age of Empires 3 cause it works slightly better (apart from the fact that when i complete all objectives it doesn't end the mission, sometimes have to leave the game running for an hour before the flag is detected)

Answer (score 0):

Try running in compatibility mode.

Right click the game icon and select properties. Now select the compatibility tab and select windows XP service pack 2. This should help Windows 8 users.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a disappearing mouse cursor. Turning off EVGA precision X16 solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The normalmouse switch fixed it for me. Example below.

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Games\Age of Empires II\empires2.exe" normalmouse

Answer (score 0):

Running the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Age of Empires II\Age2_x1\FixAoFE.exe` and putting "enable windowed mode" solved the problem for me. The main will be in a window but the game itself will be full screen, so this wasn't much of an issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

If resolution is changed(increased) in options during gameplay it helps in displaying the arrow cursor.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the Real Answer

Right click application and in compatibility tab use windows 7.service pack 2 
them use the normalmouse thing

It just worked for me

Answer (score -3):

[image]

***tick show location of pointer.........
open game and press ctrl key
you can find location of pointer***